# How Can I Join On Two Columns with a LinkEntity in CRM 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I am using a Link Entity to join a two entities:

```cs
LinkEntity pricelevelentity = new LinkEntity();
pricelevelentity.JoinOperator = JoinOperator.Inner;
pricelevelentity.LinkFromEntityName = "product";
pricelevelentity.LinkFromAttributeName = "productid";

pricelevelentity.LinkToEntityName = "productpricelevel";
pricelevelentity.LinkToAttributeName = "productid";
query.LinkEntities.Add(pricelevelentity);
```

The above is joining Product and ProductPriceLevel on the ProductId attribute.  I also want to add to the join Product.uomid on ProductPriceLevel.DefaultUomId

How can i do this?

Comment: Were you asking on how to join by two entities by two different columns, or was your question about returning the columns from a joined entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are attempting to return a column for a linked/joined entity to be able to perform additional filtering on the client side, `LinkEntity` has a `Column` property you should use, for example:

```cs
new QueryExpression("product")
{
    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("oumid"),
    LinkEntities =
    {
        new LinkEntity("product", "productpricelevel", "productid", "productid", JoinOperator.Inner)
        {
            Columns = new ColumnSet("defaultuomid")
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how James's answer was marked as the answer, but you can not join on more than one column using a linked entity.  You can use James's answer to return both values, and perform a join on the client side though, but CRM doesn't support this type of Join:

```sql
Select * FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.OneId = B.OneId AND A.TwoId = B.TwoId
```

If you know the value of the Product's UomId, you can add it to a where clause though:

```cs
var qe = new QueryExpression("product");
var productPriceLevel = new LinkEntity("product", "productpricelevel", "productid", "productid", JoinOperator.Inner);
qe.LinkEntities = productPriceLevel;
productPriceLevel.LinkCriteria.AddCondition("defaultuomid", ConditionOperator.Equal, product.UomId);
```

Which would effectively look like this:

```sql
Select * FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.OneId = B.OneId AND B.TwoId = 10 -- the Value of whatever the single A.TwoId value is you're looking for.
```

Comment: I think the title was a bit misleading, I assumed Kartik just wanted a column from each entity. Rather than a join on both columns.

Comment: @JamesWood I'll agree on the title being hard to figure out.  I hoped my edit made it more clear, but then again, Maybe the OP was meaning to ask the question you answered...

Comment: I think your edit matches the title and is certainly easier to understand, I'm just not sure it actually represents what the OP really wanted to know. But this confusion is often the result of poorly worded questions.

Comment: @JamesWood I'll ask the OP in a comment.